# Mongodb ISODates and $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, isodate

Currently I have an ISODate that is set for July 7th. I have a string that is July 7th. I am trying to isolate those specific occurences in InvoiceDate. I have tried this:

$match{InvoiceDate: {"$dateFromParts":{'year':year,'month':month,'day':day}}}

however, I keep getting NULL for my array. I do not know what is wrong here. Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment library for this, specifying the date format in the string you are passing:

```
/* set to 12:00:00 am 17 July 2018 */
const start = moment('7-17-2018', 'M-DD-YYYY').startOf('day').toDate(); 

/* set to 11:59:59 pm 17 July 2018 */
const end = moment('7-17-2018', 'M-DD-YYYY').endOf('day').toDate();

collection.find({ 'invoiceDate': { '$gte': start, '$lte': end }  })
     .toArray((err, data) => console.log(data))
```

or with aggregate

```
collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        'invoiceDate': { '$gte': start, '$lte': end }  
    } } 
], (err, data) => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter mongodb documents for particular date like this.

`$match([{invoiceDate:$gte:moment(date_to_check).startOf('day'),$lte:moment(date_to_check).endOf('day')}}])`

Try this

Comment: I am unable to get that to work: I have put in: $match({invoiceDate:{$gte:moment('7-17-2018').startOf('day'),$lte:moment(date_to_check).endOf('day')}})

Comment: you are missing date_to_check in endOf day part. most importantly did install moment like npm i moment to use moment library

Comment: $match({invoiceDate:{$gte:moment('7-17-2018').startOf('day'),$lte:moment('7-17-2018').endOf('day')}}) --- Just checked it didn't work keeps giving me an error regarding moment's parenthesis. I have also installed the moment package.

Comment: collection.aggregate([{
    $match({invoiceDate:{$gte:moment('7-17-2018').startOf('day'),$lte:moment('7-17-2018').endOf('day')}})
  }
  ])